# Doxygen not properly recognizing properties

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I have a definition on Objective-C that looks like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) BOOL myProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2);
```

When parsing this header file with Doxygen, it gets the type as "BOOL myprop", the name as "NS_AVAILABLE_IOS" and the arguments as "(3_2)".

Is there any way of making Doxygen recognize this properly without adding comments (I can't modify the files)? Maybe making it ignore the NS_AVAILABLE_IOS macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let doxygen's preprocessor remove the macro invocation. To do this use the following configuration settings:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(x)=
```

See http://www.doxygen.org/manual/preprocessing.html for details.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to post this, but I discovered that yesterday and was playing with it, very useful indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myProperty;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isWorking) BOOL myProperty;
```

Comment: I specified that I cannot modify the original files. I know that removing those macros will make Doxygen behave, but I need to do it without touching them.